# Vector bundles and groups

Tags: group-theory, differential-geometry, definition, vector-bundles

I know what a definition of a vector bundle (line bundle) is, but in the papers I am currently working on, they use the term $G$-vector bundle, where $G$ is a group.

Can somebody explain what this means?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3):

Any fiber bundle (no matter whether the fiber is a vector space or not) has a *structure group*, which is the group of all transformations that could arise in the transition maps.

A $G$-bundle is a bundle where the transition maps have to be elements of $G$. It follows that $G$ must act on the fiber, in a way that is made explicit beforehand. Where the fibers are vector spaces, it is required that transition maps preserve that structure, and therefore the structure group is a subgroup of $GL(n,\Bbb k)$.

Comment: Thanks a lot! But what do you mean by "transformations" in the transition maps?